# ActiveSupport Inflection library for Past Tense in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a past tense library for ruby, to convert words into the past tense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Past tense of English verbs is a lot more complicated than pluralization. You'll need a lingustic analysis engine and a corresponding database (due to the irregularity of the English language). If you're interested in pursuing this further, you can look at [Ruby-WordNet](https://github.com/ged/ruby-wordnet) which uses the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) lexical database.

Answer (score 21):

Check out the 'verbs' ruby gem ( [github](https://github.com/rossmeissl/verbs) | [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/verbs) | [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/verbs/2.1.0/frames) ).

Type this in the command-line:

```
gem install verbs
```

Add this to your gemfile:

```
gem "verbs", "~> 2.1.0"
```

And make sure to restart your rails server and exit your rails console before implementing.